# Magento - Global messages disappeared from Cart page, showing on CMS pages instead

Tags: php, magento

So in the past couple of days, a weird bug has arisen in a development install of Magento CE.

The Global Messages (eg when a product is added to cart) have disappeared from the Cart page (despite the code being in the template, and working last week) and are now showing on the CMS pages as well as the Home page (again, this wasn't the case last week, and I have made sure the code is not in the template)

Code I have in the Cart template in an attempt to show the messages:

```php
// This code was in the file originally, worked, but no its broken
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

// Added this in today to see if it worked, no dice
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

Comment: Just to be sure - did you do anything with layouts? Maybe some new layout removes global_messages block?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this the messages are coming up on the home and cms pages are because Magento 'hold in' all the global messages until it has a chance to spit them out to the user.

So since you didn't output it on this template, it outputs it at the first opportuninty (CMS page, or Home page).

The code you need to spit out the messages is:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages()->getGroupedHtml();
```

Hope this was helpful.

Pesach

Comment: Any idea why the cart isn't spitting the message out on the cart? I even tried the default template, and that isn't showing the message on the cart either. I found some code to add in and now messages show again, but they are still persisting when I navigate to a CMS page (that have the global message code removed from the phtml files - pretty darn weird)

Comment: you might need to flush / delete the messages once you display them

Comment: What I cannot fathom is how the messages are being displayed on the CMS pages, when I have removed all code related to Global Messages in the page template files.

Comment: it might be called within a sub block of your template (or in a parent). another option is that the cache needs to be flushed. you also might consider and observer that might be flushing output

Comment: I searched the base template and mine for "$this->getChildHtml('global_notices')" and "$this->getChildHtml('global_messages')" and all instances are commented out, in both templates. Yet the message saying a product has been added to the cart still appears on CMS pages. Cache has been cleared manually via FTP and via the backend controls.

Comment: if you want to remove the add to cart message permanently go to: app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php and then and remove the line that reads'$message .= $this->__(’%s was added to your shopping cart. ‘, Mage::helper(’core’)->htmlEscape($product->getName()));'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15479/discussion-between-pzirkind-and-mr-pablo)